# React native page navigation is bit slow because of static components rendering

Tags: reactjs, native, react-navigation

Whenever I'm navigating from one components to other the loading of another component is taking a pause of 2 to 3 seconds , and I have found that this is because of next components render element. So is there any way you make it faster?

How can I improve the components rendering performance.

Currently using redux , redux saga and react-navigation

Any suggestions or improvement will be really helpful.

Comment: Well without a single line of code it will be hard to guess what could be the problem.

Comment: @trixn - Yup, bdw i have fixed the issue, the issue was because of debug mode.